# Getting None trying to Web-Scrape all the article titles on the Ny-times front page

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to get the article titles from the ny-times webpage, but when I tried to print all the titles with a for loop I get a list of some titles but mostly none.

Sometimes I get nothing but NONE.

How can I make it so it only prints the article titles?

Tried using both xhtml and html.parser, not sure what I'm really doing though. Was following a youtube tutorial on scraping for an exercise but the nytimes page is very congested with web tags.

Tried just sarching 'div' as well, without the class label.

Tried dropping the .text

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


    url = "https://www.nytimes.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
    r_html = r.text


    soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, 'html.parser')

    for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='css-1ez5fsm esl82me1'):
        headline = article.h2.span
        print(headline)
```

I expected all the article titles to print.

Comment: This close to what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533759/return-empty-bracket-when-web-scrapping/57534924#57534924  I know there are several other others if you look through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=PYTHON%20https%3a%2f%2fwww.nytimes.com)

Comment: A quick look at the source data shows that not all of the titles are in spans, only some.